# Changing Searchable Icon in Actionbar

Tags: android, searchable

I'm implementing searchable for my application and I come to this problem. How can i change the default magnifying glass for my Searchable? The default looks big and fugly and I prefer to use the same drawable i used for my menu icon.

[image: Big fugly manifying glass]

Searching "icon" in [Searchable Configuration - Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config.html) website doesn't lead to any useful information. I also tried by adding `android:icon`(It was an option in the `Structure` tab) to my searchable definition but it's not working.

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_custom_test"
    android:includeInGlobalSearch="true"
    android:label="@string/search_label"
    android:searchSettingsDescription="@string/settings_description"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.test.provider.SuggestionProvider"
    android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"
    android:searchSuggestIntentData="content://com.test.provider.SuggestionProvider/info"
    android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?"
    android:searchSuggestThreshold="1" >
</searchable>
```

Thanks in advance for any helps!

Comment: Are you changed it yet? please help because I'm asking your question.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own searchview, delete the **search** item from main.xml/activity_main(your layout filename) in menu folder, then create a new item and your own search icon,.,

*use iconfinder.com for different icons.*

in your activity, in options method, create a switch case and add the functionality when you click on this item.,.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       SearchManager localSearchManager1 = (SearchManager)getSystemService("search");
        SearchView localSearchView1 = (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        localSearchView1.setSearchableInfo(localSearchManager1.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        localSearchView1.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
        {
         SearchManager localSearchManager2 = (SearchManager)getSystemService("search");
          SearchView localSearchView2 = (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
          localSearchView2.setSearchableInfo(localSearchManager2.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
          localSearchView2.setIconifiedByDefault(true) ;
        }
```

Comment: Hi yahya, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your answer would be a lot more "useful" if you provided a short explanation in addition to the code snippet - its the useful answers that get upvotes ;)